# jquery.js and bootstrap.js conflict

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

when jquery.js and bootstrap.js active, button form action can't run. But when jquery.js command, button signin (`tg-btnsignin`) can't run.

this is script code:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/js/vendor/jquery-library.js'); ?>"></script>
```

this is my form code:

```
<form class="tg-formtheme tg-formtrip" 
        method = "GET" 
        action = "<?php echo site_url('Home/search'); ?>" >
```

this is my signin code:

```
<div class="tg-userbox">
<a id="tg-btnsignin" class="tg-btn" href="#tg-loginsingup">
    <span>sign in</span>
</a>
```

Comment: do you receive a js error? can you post the js activating `#tg-btnsignin`?

Comment: thanks for reply sir, already solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `jQuery` before bootstrap.

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/js/vendor/jquery-library.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');?>"></script>
```

Comment: Put both of them at the end of your document before the ending `</body>` tag. Make sure that you `php` is returning correct URL (check the code from browser source)